# How to align text with a imagen using Bootstrap and Css

Tags: css

Im creating a web app and I need to know how to align images with text. Right now, I have this:
[image]

What I want it to have the image on the left with it description on the right. The code Im using is this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91epzdXTTHL._SX300_.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:20%">
      <div class="caption">
        <pelicula tipo="accion" calificacion="Mayores de 13" estreno="26 de abril de 2019" ></pelicula>
        <titulo>Titulo: Avengers Engame</titulo><br />
        <director>Dirección: Joe and Anthony Russo</director><br />
        <productor>Producción: Kevin Feige</productor><br />
        <guion>Guión: Cristhoper Markus y Stephen McFeely</guion><br />
        <musica>Música: Alan Silvestri</musica><br />
        <duracion>Duración: 181 minutos</duracion><br />
        <productora>Productora: Marvel Studios</productora><br />
        <Presupuesto>Presupuesto: 356.000.000 $</Presupuesto><br />
        <Recaudacion>Recaudación: 2.800.000.000 $</Recaudacion><br /
        <Comentarios> Comentario: Una de las peliculas mas esperadas del año. El desenlace final la guerra del infinito. </Comentarios><br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using Bootstrap. Bootstrap has a grid system. Any reason you can't use that?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a Codepen example, it would be useful to other developers. 
Anyway, you can accomplish this with the [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/):

```
.thumbnail {
  display: flex;
}
```

Another way would be to use the bootstrap grid or using CSS `float`.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap flex to do https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex align-items-center p-2 text-white-50 rounded shadow-sm" style="background-color:var(--purple)">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91epzdXTTHL._SX300_.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:30%">
  <div class="lh-100 ml-3">
    <div class="caption">
      <pelicula tipo="accion" calificacion="Mayores de 13" estreno="26 de abril de 2019"></pelicula>
      <titulo>Titulo: Avengers Engame</titulo><br />
      <director>Dirección: Joe and Anthony Russo</director><br />
      <productor>Producción: Kevin Feige</productor><br />
      <guion>Guión: Cristhoper Markus y Stephen McFeely</guion><br />
      <musica>Música: Alan Silvestri</musica><br />
      <duracion>Duración: 181 minutos</duracion><br />
      <productora>Productora: Marvel Studios</productora><br />
      <Presupuesto>Presupuesto: 356.000.000 $</Presupuesto><br />
      <Recaudacion>Recaudación: 2.800.000.000 $</Recaudacion><br / <Comentarios> Comentario: Una de las peliculas mas esperadas del año. El desenlace final la guerra del infinito. </Comentarios><br />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with flex function in css. Add display: flex; to .thumbnail class. If you don't know about display flex refer below sites.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="background: yellowgreen;">
 <div class="thumbnail" style="display: flex;padding: 10px;">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91epzdXTTHL._SX300_.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:20%;">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-left: 20px; ">
            <pelicula tipo="accion" calificacion="Mayores de 13" estreno="26 de abril de 2019" ></pelicula>
            <titulo>Titulo: Avengers Engame</titulo><br />
            <director>Dirección: Joe and Anthony Russo</director><br />
             <productor>Producción: Kevin Feige</productor><br />
             <guion>Guión: Cristhoper Markus y Stephen McFeely</guion><br />
            <musica>Música: Alan Silvestri</musica><br />
            <duracion>Duración: 181 minutos</duracion><br />
            <productora>Productora: Marvel Studios</productora><br />
            <Presupuesto>Presupuesto: 356.000.000 $</Presupuesto><br />
           <Recaudacion>Recaudación: 2.800.000.000 $</Recaudacion><br /
          <Comentarios> Comentario: Una de las peliculas mas esperadas del año. El desenlace final la guerra del infinito. </Comentarios><br />
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```